# Which clustering or distance metric is appropriate?

Tags: clustering, distance

I need some help finding the correct direction to go in.  Here is the problem:

I have a dataset of unique devices, and each device has a count of the number of service tickets opened in each of 4 categories.  Here is some sample data.

[image]

For each device ID *separately*, I need to determine if the ticket types are clustering or grouping in some way, and if so, which types are most common.  A cursory look at these data might suggest that:

- ID #1: there is grouping, Type 1 is most common
- ID #2: does not appear to be grouping
- ID #3: grouping, Type 1 and Type 3 most common
- ID #4: grouping, Type 4 is most common

I realize that my definition of 'grouping' is very lax, and that is where I need assistance.

Should I be looking at particular distance metrics? perhaps proportional? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a first step, you may want to normalize each row by its vector norm. This will remove the effect of some IDs having more overall tickets.

Answer (score 1):

Latent class analysis would be an appropriate choice for finding any underlying or hidden groupings in your typology. I made this same suggestion earlier today on a question about grouping illicit drug users by the drugs they ingested...here... [What are the statistical methods I can use to find popular or common combinations of categorical variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179162/what-are-the-statistical-methods-i-can-use-to-find-popular-or-common-combination/179178#179178)

Everything said there applies to your situation.

Comment: the difference, I think, is that I have no real inherent variability in the data.  In the illicit drug example, the latent classes use information from the distribution of respondents, whereas I am basically considering each device ID independently.

Comment: The LC model would cross-classify the types by ignoring the device IDs, thereby creating the "inherent variability" needed to partition the residual.

Answer (score 0):

This is not **clustering** what you are describing.

Instead, you apparently want to **test uniform distribution** of the ticket severities.

There are many measures from information theory such as Shannon entropy that may be of interest to you.