# What statistical methods can I use to determine the popularity of item combinations taken from two groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clustering, combinatorics, association-measure, association-rules

Let's say I have two tables, listing projects with the programming languages and frameworks they use:

```
| ProjectID | ProgrammingLanguageID |
| --------- | --------------------- |
| 1         | 32                    |
| 2         | 27                    |
| 3         | 8                     |
```

And:

```
| ProjectID | FrameworkID           |
| --------- | --------------------- |
| 1         | 3                     |
| 1         | 7                     |
| 2         | 5                     |
```

The general rule is a project can use more than one framework but only one programming language. I would like to find out what language-framework combinations there are, and the most common ones. Is there any suitable statistical analysis I could apply?

Comment: Isn't this purely a programming question?  Could you explain what a statistical analysis would amount to?

Comment: @whuber My apologies, I meant “statistical method”, not “analysis”. I am looking for a solution that is probably close to the ones mentioned in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179162/what-are-the-statistical-methods-i-can-use-to-find-popular-or-common-combination), but the variables are from two different tables.